# How can I change the screen resolution of PhantomJS?

Tags: python, node.js, selenium, phantomjs, phantomjs-node

In any way I can not find a question concerning change of the sanction of the screen.
There will always be `1024x768`.
Changing the viewportSize does not change the screen resolution, by itself.
I checked the resolution here: [link](http://browserspy.dk/screen.php)

This is for node:

```
var WebPage = require('webpage');
page = WebPage.create()

page.onInitialized = function () {
    page.evaluate(function () {
        window.screen = {width: 1600, height: 900, availWidth: 1600, availHeight: 900};
    });
};

page.open('http://browserspy.dk/screen.php');
page.onLoadFinished = function () {
    page.render('ScreenShot' + '.png');
    phantom.exit();
}
```

**Can anyone remake for the python?**

Comment: did you find solution ? I can't find anything either and its bothering the hell out of me :-/

Comment: VladoPortos, docker+selenium or casperjs only i think

Answer (score 1):

Try using viewportSize. Refer this link [ViewPortSize](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html)

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 480,
  height: 800
};
```

Comment: On my post: "Changing the viewportSize does not change the screen resolution"